# Next.js Script only loading on Navigation, not hard refresh/first load

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm really struggling to fix an issue with a script I'm trying to load inside my Next.js application. I've tried countless ways to fix it, (including hours with Chat-GPT4 haha) ,including using the next native Script component. For some reason when I use the Next Script component, I get the opposite problem (it only loads on a hard refresh).

Essentially this is the AdComponent, it loads fine if you navigate to the page through an internal Next link. However if you arrive on the page first, or hard refresh, it never loads. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SongType } from '@/generated/graphql';

type Props = {
    song: SongType
    ad_id: number;
}

const loadScript = (src: any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = () => resolve(script);
        script.onerror = () => reject(new Error('Failed to load script'));
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
};

const AdComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ song, ad_id = 100006001 }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect triggered");

        const runAds = () => {
            if (typeof window.amplified === 'undefined') {
                window.amplified = { init: [] };
                console.log("Initializing window.amplified");
            }
            console.log("running ads")
            window.amplified.init.push(function () {
                window.amplified.setParams({
                    artist: song?.artist?.name,
                    song: song?.name,
                }).pushAdUnit(ad_id);
                window.amplified.ad_units[ad_id].fetch();
            });
        };

        let scriptExists = false;
        for (let script of Array.from(document.scripts)) {
            if (script.src === "//srv.clickfuse.com/ads/ads.js") {
                scriptExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (scriptExists) {
            runAds();
        } else {
            loadScript('//srv.clickfuse.com/ads/ads.js')
                .then(() => runAds())
                .catch((error) => console.error('Failed to load script:', error));
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <div id={`amplified_${ad_id}`}></div>
    );
};

export default AdComponent;
```